# Oracle database listner.ora configuration is not read during listener startup

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have configured following two configuration files of oracle database.

`/opt/oracle/11.2.0/network/admin/listener.ora` to have following values

```
ADR_BASE_LISTENER = /opt/oracle



LISTENER_JIPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
          (DESCRIPTION =
                (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain)(PORT = 1530))
          )
  )

SID_LIST_LSNR_JIPDB =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DWJP02T)
      (ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/11.2.0)
      (SID_NAME = DWJP02T)
    )
  )
```

and I have configured `/opt/oracle/11.2.0/network/admin/tnsnames.ora`
file to have following values

```
LISTENER_JIPDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost.localdomain )(PORT = 1530))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = DWJP02T)
    )
  )
```

My question is when i try to start the oracle listner by typing following command, 
it is opening the DWJP02T SID instance in 1521 port, i don't know how it is getting this port or from where it is reading this port, I have configured to it to read 1530 on the .ora files.

this is the output i get when i start the listner

```
[ora112@localhost ~]$ lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production on 26-DEC-2012 22:48:16

Copyright (c) 1991, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting /opt/oracle/11.2.0/bin/tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
System parameter file is /opt/oracle/11.2.0/network/admin/listener.ora
Log messages written to /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.3.0 - Production
Start Date                26-DEC-2012 22:48:16
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 0 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/11.2.0/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost.localdomain)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

Please help me to understand why it is opening database on different port than what i have configred it to start. I restarted the database and the server to see if it will read values from the listner.ora file, but still no luck.

Answer (score 5):

Try these steps to furnish the request:

- Stop the Oracle listener using the following command:

  ```
  lsnrctl stop
  ```
- Change the port number in the Oracle listener.ora file. For example, from the default port 1522 to 1521.
- Change the port number in the tnsnames.ora file as in the following example, where `host_name` is your host name and `server_name` is your server name.
- Restart the Oracle listener using the following command:

  ```
  lsnrctl start
  ```
- Change the port to which the database is listening:

  ```
  sqlplus / as sysdba        
  > alter system set LOCAL_LISTENER="(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1522))";        
  > alter system register;
  ```